# image naturalWidth return zero

Tags: javascript

image naturalWidth return zero... that's it, why ?

```
var newimage = new Image();
newimage.src = 'retouche-hr' + newlinkimage.substring(14,17) + '-a.jpg'; 
var width = newimage.naturalWidth;
alert (width);
```

HELP, i dont know why !

*** that path is good, the image show up !

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I'd guess it's because you're not waiting for the image to load - try this:

```
var newimage = new Image();
newimage.src = 'retouche-hr' + newlinkimage.substring(14,17) + '-a.jpg'; 
newimage.onload = function()
{
    var width = this.naturalWidth;
    alert(width);
}
```

Comment: The order in which `src` and `onload` are set is important for the load callback to get called.

Comment: Hmm I tested in Chrome and Firefox and they both worked OK. IE showed the alert too but doesn't support naturalWidth

Comment: (It's 2016 and) IE>=9 supports `naturalWidth` and `naturalHeight` according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement#Browser_compatibility) :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the FINAL WORKING CODE... in case somebody wants to know. It's all a matter of waiting until the images have loaded!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#thumb").jCarouselLite({
            btnNext: "#down",
            btnPrev: "#up",
            vertical: true,
            visible: 4
        });

        $("#thumb li img").click(function() {
            var newlinkimage = $(this).attr("src");
            newlinkimage = 'retouche-hr' + newlinkimage.substring(14,17);

            $('#hr').remove();

            var newimage = new Image();
            newimage.src = newlinkimage + '-a.jpg';

            newimage.onload = function()
            {
                var width = (newimage.width);
                var height = (newimage.height);

                $('#contentfull').append('<div id="hr"> </div>');
                $("#hr").attr("width", width).attr("height", height);
                $("#hr").addClass('hrviewer');
                //alert('a');
                $("#hr").append('<div id="avant"> <img alt="before" src="' + newlinkimage +'-a.jpg"></div>');
                $("#hr").append('<div id="apres"> <img alt="after" src="' + newlinkimage +'-b.jpg"></div>');
                //alert('b');
                $("#avant img").attr("src", newlinkimage + '-a.jpg').attr("width", width).attr("height", height);
                $("#apres img").attr("src", newlinkimage + '-b.jpg').attr("width", width).attr("height", height);

                $("#apres img").load(function(){$("#hr").beforeAfter({animateIntro:true});});        
            }  
        })
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the following works ...

```
    $('<img src="mypathtotheimage.png"/>').load(function () {

        if (!isNotIe8) {
            // ie8 need a fix
            var image = new Image(); // or document.createElement('img')
            var width, height;
            image.onload = function () {
                width = this.width;
                height = this.height;
            };
            image.src = $(this).attr("src");

        } else {
            // everythings fine here ....
            // this.naturalWidth / this.naturalHeight;
        }
```