# How to get HTTP status code of <img> tags

Tags: javascript, image, http-status-codes

I have a page with a lot of images that are generated server-side depending on user actions. And when image loads successfully I'm happy, but when there is an error on the server I have to act according to what an error occurred.

For example:

- 500 code: do this stuff.
- 503 code: do that stuff

and so on.

**So, my question**: is there any way to get status code within "img" tag on-error event handler?

Comment: Why the hell would you ever handle such issues on the client? Why don't you get the server to handle these images properly?

Comment: @Raynos the situation is such: images are created dynamicaly on the server, but it takes a lot of time, which means some of them won't be ready when browser asks for them. At the same time some critical error may occur on the server-side and there will be no image at all. So, based on http status, I have to ask server for images once again, or just inform user, about error.

Comment: No, your still doing it wrong. You have a HTTP server, when you get an incoming GET request for an image you can "wait" for it to be ready. And if a critical error occured you can return a "critical error" image.

Comment: @Raynos unfortunately, I'm working only on the front-end, and don't have access for the back-end. I'm not happy with the conditions of the problem. As far as I know server cannot afford keeping lots of open connections, so I can only ask whether image is ready or not, not waiting for the image to be ready.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, there is no way to get the HTTP status from a request made by an `img` tag in JavaScript.

You could write a firefox plugin, chrome/safari extension to do that.

An alternative would be using AJAX to load your images (not using `img` tags). You can get Http Status Codes from Ajax Requests.

Comment: Plugin is not acceptable. AJAX seems to be fine, but what kind of data should I get through AJAX? I can retrieve the image data, but I can't use it to create img element.

Comment: You would most likely need to send it as a data url. You'll probably need to find some kind of library that can generate data urls on the server side. Then once they arrive it's just a matter of setting the img's src to the data url. This will add a good deal of overhead to loading your images. The real solution is probably to fix the server so it always successfully sends images.

Comment: Ajax is not a good substitution in case, your wanna-load-images are placed on external domain. Anything new about this issue in 2016?

Answer (score 7):

You cannot check HTTP status this way. However you can check if image was loaded or not using  naturalWidth property.

```
if (img.naturalWidth === 0) {
    // do sth
}
```

Hope it help.

Comment: For anyone reading this page, the naturalWidth property is not supported by all browsers. This property is also quite touchy - you should only attempt to read it after the image has loaded. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1645166/image-naturalwidth-return-zero)

I hope that helps. :)

Comment: @Axle You are referring to the post from '09. Now it works in all latest browsers version.

Comment: I happen to work somewhere that makes it a requirement to support older browsers (IE 7 and IE 8 for example). I'm sure there are others out there that suffer a similar fate. 

Trust me, screaming "Well they should just update their broken tools!" never got me anywhere. :P

Comment: @Axle Well, there is no IE7 or 8 since upgrade to IE9 is forced. If somebody has older version its mean it is pirate Windows version :- ) Anyway I (and company I'm working for) don't care about anything that is not latest. In fact I only test stuff in Google Chrome, when works is fine.

Comment: That's nice. This discussion, however, is quite pointless. Fact of the matter is, there are people out there that do use the older browsers (government included), and some of us have to support it. My initial comment was not an attack on you - it was meant for the other poor saps, like myself, forced to support legacy browsers. And that's all I have to say about that.

Comment: (Looks like I missed the grace period to append this to the above comment)

I'd also like to add: Can I work where you are?

Comment: @Axie, Wojciech, `img.complete` is what you should look at to see if an image is loaded or not, or for guaranteed compatibility you could attach to the onload event.

Comment: As per Microsoft support policy it looks like they would support it till 12 January 2016. So as a developer we should also make sure that our web pages works in it till then.

Answer (score 3):

You may combine the couple technics to get img.status:

```
<img src="/no.img" onerror="error(this)">

function error(img) {
   var r = makeXMLHttpRequestAgain(img.src);
   if (r.status === 500) img.src = '/e500.img';
   if (r.status === 503) img.src = '/e503.img';
}
```

Comment: Source of  `makeXMLHttpRequestAgain`?

Comment: @Tino, makeXMLHttpRequestAgain is not implemented yet. The idea is to make XMLHttpRequest to get the status code.

Comment: My problem is, `<img>` is loaded with status code `200` (usually, except a few cases) while `XMLHttpRequest` returns `402` due to how `XMLHttpRequest` or `fetch` work.  The web page is under my control while the `<img>`-site isn't.  The `<img>` site protects against linking images from unauthorized sites.  My site is authorized.  `.decode()` does not work either, as `.decode()` often fails while the `<img>` looks ok.  `.naturalWidth` works but gives no hint why or how the `<img>` failed, i.E. if it is `402`, `404`, `408` or `500` etc.  AFAICS only a browser extension can fix this ..

Comment: In your case a free generate ssl certificate solves your problem.

Comment: Throwing additional SSL onto this does not help as it is already present.  The `<img>`-site (which is NOT under my control) is like `https://images.example.`net`/image.jpg` while my website (which IS under my control) is like `https://www.example.`org`/img.html`

Answer (score 1):

```
 function loadBinaryImageAndInsertToImgTag(imgElement, imageUrl) {
        let xhr = getXMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onreadystatechange = ProcessResponse;
        xhr.open("GET", imageUrl, true);
        xhr.overrideMimeType('text/plain; charset=x-user-defined');
        xhr.send(null);

        function getXMLHttpRequest() {
            let xhr = null;

            if (window.XMLHttpRequest || window.ActiveXObject) {
                if (window.ActiveXObject) {
                    try {
                        xhr = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                    } catch (e) {
                        xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                    }
                } else {
                    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                }
            } else {
                alert("Your browser does not support XMLHTTP");
                return null;
            }
            return xhr;
        }

        function ProcessResponse() {
            if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
                if (xhr.status === 200) {
                    imgElement.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + encode64(xhr.responseText);
                    imgElement.style.display = "";
                } else {
                    alert("Error retrieving data!");
                }
            }
        }

        function encode64(inputStr) {
            let b64 = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=";
            let outputStr = "";
            let i = 0;

            while (i < inputStr.length) {
                let byte1 = inputStr.charCodeAt(i++) & 0xff;
                let byte2 = inputStr.charCodeAt(i++) & 0xff;
                let byte3 = inputStr.charCodeAt(i++) & 0xff;
                let enc1 = byte1 >> 2;
                let enc2 = ((byte1 & 3) << 4) | (byte2 >> 4);
                let enc3, enc4;
                if (isNaN(byte2)) {
                    enc3 = enc4 = 64;
                }
                else {
                    enc3 = ((byte2 & 15) << 2) | (byte3 >> 6);
                    if (isNaN(byte3)) {
                        enc4 = 64;
                    }
                    else {
                        enc4 = byte3 & 63;
                    }
                }
                outputStr += b64.charAt(enc1) + b64.charAt(enc2) + b64.charAt(enc3) + b64.charAt(enc4);
            }
            return outputStr;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why `encode64` instead of [`btoa`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/btoa)?

Answer (score -6):

You have to add an eventListener on images :

For example with jQuery :

```
$('#your_image')
    .error(function(e) {
        //add your unhappy code here

        //unbind if needed
        $(this).unbind('error');
    })
    .load(function(e) {
        //add your happy code here

        //unbind if needed
        $(this).unbind('load');
    })
    ;
```

Comment: Please note that, from the [API for `.error()`:](http://api.jquery.com/api/error/) "The event handler **must** be attached **before** the browser fires the error event, which is why the example sets the src attribute **after** attaching the handler." (**emphases** mine).

Comment: just throw some jQuery at it, surely it will solve the problem!