# How to detect if any of css/js files failed to load and alert user to refresh browser

Tags: javascript

I am facing a weird issue where sometimes all the files are not loaded from the server and hence resulting in broken web page. I can simply check for angular like `window.angular !== 'undefined`, but there are like 20-25 script tags for each library and I cannot check for each one of them

It would be nice if we can alert the user by detecting if any of the css/js files fail to load.

Comment: You have the `onerror` event (https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror) which you can bind to a `<script>` for example

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8504673/how-to-detect-on-page-404-errors-using-javascript read this