# How to get the status code for dynamically created script tag?

Tags: javascript

My code dynamically creates a `<script>` tag and attached it to the DOM tree. However, if for some reason the script fails to load, I need to figure out why. The `event` object passed to `onerror` callback does not show any information about why the script fails to load. I would like to at least get the status code of the request so I can determine if that's a 404 or 500. Is this possible?

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8108636/how-to-get-http-status-code-of-img-tags) someone says that it is not possible to get the status code for `<img>` tag. I'm wondering if that also true for `<script>` tag.

Comment: My guess would be that using the `<script>` tag will work the same as `img` and you will not be able to get the status, but if you will use ajax request (before adding the `<script>` tag) you will be able to get the error and the status.

Comment: If trying to figure out why, instead of handling it, why not just use the devtools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to **[XML.com](https://www.xml.com/pub/a/2005/12/21/json-dynamic-script-tag.html)**,

> The most notable downside [of the script tag] is that it cannot handle errors gracefully. If the web service returns an invalid JavaScript statement to the script tag, a JavaScript error will be generated. If the web service returns invalid JSON wrapped inside a callback function, a JavaScript error will be returned when the invalid JSON data is passed to the callback function. If your web service returns an HTTP return code other than 200 (successful), then the script tag will silently fail.

So no, there is no way to determine a non-200 status code of a dynamic `<script>` tag.

Having said that, if you use an AJAX request, you will be able to get both the status code and error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try to fetch the script first and catch all errors information
If fetch success u can load the script from the blob.
U can find my full solution [here](https://medium.com/@genautkin/load-javascript-to-html-in-order-and-parallel-ba86b44bd896)

```
const loadScriptWithFetchFirst = function (url, includeCrossOrigin = true) {
return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
   fetch(url,{ mode: includeCrossOrigin ? 'cors' : 'no-cors'})
            .then((response) => {
                if (!response.ok) {
                     reject(`Can't load script ${url} error: ${response.status}; ${response.statusText}`);
                     return null;
                }
                else {
                    return response.blob()} 
                })
            .then((blob) => {
                if (blob !== null) {
                    return;
                }
                const objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                const script = document.createElement('script');
                script.src = objectURL;
                if (includeCrossOrigin) {
                    script.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
                }
                script.onload = function () {
                    resolve(true);
                }
                script.onerror = function (event) {
                    reject(event ? event : '')
                };
                document.head.appendChild(script);
            })
            .catch((e)=>{
                reject(`Request failed: ${e}`);
            })
});
```

};

Comment: Interesting approach! Just remember that 'isNullOrUndefined' is not a thing in pure JS