# How to check for error codes (e.g. 403) when loading script dynamically?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

In my app, I have a function that loads scripts dynamically. I would like to give more specific feedback to the user when there is an error during the script-load time. That is why I would like to add logic that checks for the status codes (e.g. `403` - not authenticated).

Bellow is the script tha I use to load scripts:

```
private _scripts: { [key: string]: Subject<Event> } = {};

load(url: string): Observable<Event> {
    if (this._scripts[url]) {
        return this._scripts[url];
    }

    this._scripts[url] = new ReplaySubject<Event>(1);

    let script = this.document.createElement("script");
    script.src = url;
    script.onload = (event: Event) => {
        this._scripts[url].next(event);
        this._scripts[url].complete();
    };
    script.onerror = (error: string | Event) => {
        this._scripts[url].error(error);
    };
    
    this.document.head.appendChild(script);

    return this._scripts[url].asObservable();
}
```

The problem with the script above is that there is no error code being returned in the `onerror` callback function. That is because the error code is being thrown on the `this.document.head.appendChild(script);` line when the `script` element is added to the DOM.

I have tried wrapping the logic in `try-catch` but that didn't work and the catch statement didn't get invoked at all. Below is a snippet of my browser's console showing that the the breakpoint I have in the `catch` statement is not getting hit

[image]

What would be the best way in my situation to catch the error code?

Comment: I think the `onerror` is the way to go. Try adding a breakpoint to your `onerror` handler, make sure it isn't actually getting called. Also, you may have some other errors here. It's kind of strange to assign `document` to a property on an object, for example. Make sure nothing's getting logged in your debug console.

Comment: @loremdipso The `onerror` handler is getting called and information is logged in the console (see https://i.imgur.com/3MHNQSB.png). However, it doesn't provide me with anything useful to check if the error is indeed `403`. It just provides information about that fact that it was not able to load the script.

Comment: Maybe check out this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8108636/how-to-get-http-status-code-of-img-tags), then. Basically they re-request the same resource using AJAX, which does provide a status code.