# Obtain background image width

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

is possible to get background image width which is defined in CSS?

```
body {
    background-image: url('background.jpg');
}
```

I need something like this:

```
window.getComputedStyle(document.body, 'background-width');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var u = window.getComputedStyle(document.body, 'background-image');
u = u.replace(/url\(/, '').replace(/\)/, '');
var w = 0;
var i = new Image();
i.onload = function( ){ w = this.width; alert(w); }
i.src = u;
```

warning: *i have ommitted a case, when body has no background image specified, keep that in mind.*

Answer (score 1):

> is possible to get background image width which is defined in CSS?

I don't think so, but you should be able to use a little trick : Load the image into an `img` element as described [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643858/image-native-width-in-jquery).

If you do this after the document has been fully loaded, the browser should fetch the image from the cache.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to do this directly without some sort of work around.

1. Use JQuery to detect what image the background has, with the [imagesLoaded](https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded) (recommended) or [onImagesLoad](http://www.cirkuit.net/projects/jquery/onImagesLoad/) plugin.
2. Use the JQuery [Dimensions plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/dimensions) to get the image size.